# how to run a .apk file on blackberry phone?

Tags: android, blackberry, apk

I want to install my Android app on a BlackBerry device. Can someone please provide me with some information?

Comment: .apk won't run on Blackberry OS.

Comment: but is there any way to do so, or covert the apk into a .cod/.bar file so as to run on blackberry phone?

Comment: BlackBerry OS runs .COD files

Answer (score 6, accepted):

At this time, the only BlackBerry device that can run Android apps is the PlayBook running OS 2.0. If you have a developer account with BlackBerry, sign in and you can find an on-line tool to test your app for compatibility and do the conversion to a .bar file.

The best place to start for documentation and how-to guidance is the [Android Development Tools forum](http://supportforums.blackberry.com/t5/BlackBerry-Plug-in-for-Android/bd-p/adt) on the support site.

Answer (score 2):

You could check out the Android Player for Blackberry

http://crackberry.com/how-use-android-app-player-and-load-apps

Although I doubt that every application will work as on its native OS

Answer (score 1):

Read [how to install the app on backbarry](http://blackberryrocks.com/how-to-install-applications-themes-blackberry-desktop-manager/).

This will help you.